# Get id using Laravel inside the select being populate with ng-options using AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, laravel, laravel-7

I am trying to get data inside the select using Laravel that is being populate with ng-options using AngularJS

**HTML**

```
<select class="form-control" ng-options="c.id as c.name for c in dataCategory" ng-model="selectedCategoryID">
 </select>
```

**AngularJS app**

```
$scope.dataCategory = [
   {'id': 1, 'name': 'Category A'},
   {'id': 2, 'name': 'Category B'}
]
```

Is there a way to get the data using Laravel?

Like for example there is a form action to

**web.php**

```
Route::post('/getCategoryID', 'CategoriesController@postEdit');
```

**CategoriesController.php**

```
public function postEdit(Request request) {
 //code here
}
```

Comment: somehow if I add a `name = "category"` in the select and get the request using the name. It will return `number:1` if I select the Category A.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. By getting the request which is `$request->get('category')` it returns `number:1`. I used `preg_replace($request->get('category')` to get only the number which is the `id`.